# Java - best practice for event handling and reflect results back

Tags: java, swing, actionlistener

Since I start to programming in Java, every time when I want to create a GUI and a more complex business logic every time I encounter the same problem.

1. How can you entirely separate the GUI part from the logic part?
   Edited: Maybe is slightly wrong said "GUI part from the logic part". Rather, more correctly is "GUI part from the listeners part" because we don't want files with a huge amount of lines like when we wrote anonymous functions or inner classes.

A result can be that:

```
public class MainFrame extends JFrame{
    private final Handler handler = new Handler();
    public MainFrame(){
        //some code...
        final JButton b = new JButton("Click Me!");
        b.putClientProperty("command", "some command or a static variable from a some commands class");
        b.addActionListener(this.handler);
    }
}

// another class in another file 
public class Handler implements ActionListener{
    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
         if(e.getSource() instanceof JButton){
             final JButton source = (JButton)e.getSource();
             if(source.getClientProperty("command").equals("some command or a static variable from a some commands class")){
                 //do something
             }
         }
    }
}
```

If some of you know a better way to do that please tell to me.

1. How to make the GUI respond with a refresh when an action is taken from? Because in the above example we wrote:

   ```
   b.addActionListener(this.handler);
   ```

so only button b knows when the action was performed.

In case that my solution for the first problem is not reliable for the second one please provide a complete solution for this post.

I hope that will be helpful for more people.

Thanks.

Comment: Your handler doesn't show any GUI changes. What do you want to happen in the handler?

Comment: @BetaRide : in my vision, the Handler class from above is more like an dispatcher: he treat the source and send actions to controller/model/etc.

Comment: @Ciobanu Andrei: It’s perfect if the handler dispatches to controller/model/etc. And there should be classes implementing Swing’s model interfaces and thus sending events if the action(s) modified model state. Then the GUI will update itself automatically as Swing components register themselves (sometimes indirectly) as listeners to the specified data model(s).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To avoid separate classes for `ActionListener`s that are only used locally, you can write them as [anonymous classes](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/anonymousclasses.html).

To propagate events in a Java application, you can use an event bus mechanism such as [Guava's `EventBus`](http://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/wiki/EventBusExplained).

Comment: Good example with Guava's EventBus, but for me the actionListener and the Guava's EventBus looks quite similar, only remarcable difference is the syntax.
Tell me if I wrong.

Comment: As an addition, starting with Java 8, arbitrary methods can be bound to action listeners without inner classes.

Answer (score 0):

Thinlet, Luxor, XUI frameworks are designed to apart GUI from business logics. you can also use MVC pattern to make it possible.

Thinlet is a GUI toolkit, a single Java class, parses the hierarchy and properties of the GUI, handles user interaction, and calls business logic.

Comment: Indeed, MVC is in my mind. But I don't want to use a framework, I want to do it myself.

Comment: MVC inspires you in your own design.

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to swing developement.

Splitting the ActionListener implementation and the panel/frame into two classes only works for simple cases. Often you want to manipulate other GUI components in the same panel.

It requires extra work to access them if your ActionListener is in an other public class. You have to feed the panel into the Handler constructor and make the GUI components accessible with public methods on the panel. After all this is just what (anonmyous) inner classes give you for free.

Maintaining the ActionListeners as inner classes of the panel is very common for swing panels. If you don't like the big source file you can use the code folding mechanism of eclipse or IntelliJ.

Comment: "It requires extra work to access them if your ActionListener is in an other public class." - What you want to say? Can you give a little example?

And about the code folding, is not about the visual effect, is about the file size, code maintenance, and probably more others principles.